# UV map either not unwrapping or is collapsing in a merge

Tags: uv

I downloaded this model.  And I'm trying to add its textures.  I get to the eyes and for some unknown reason the UV for it is just a tiny little dot in the very bottom corner of the image texture.  I have tried to unwrap it and nothing happens.  I tried to scale the UV and nothing happens.  It just stays stuck there.  This happened to a previous model as well.  I merged two objects together and the UV for one suddenly turned into a small dot.  Which makes no sense as to why.  Other objects I merged had no problem at all.  It was just those two objects.

Right now the problem seems to be just the eyes but I haven't gotten to any other part of the model yet to be sure.

[Blend file](https://d.maxfile.ro/casoixuwxx.blend)

Answer (score 1):

The eyes unwraps fine, but because it has no UV seams the generic 'Unwrap' option doesn't work. Either add seams to it to use the normal 'Unwrap' option or use a different unwrapping option like 'Sphere Projection' or 'Smart UV Project.

More information about unwrapping spheres can be found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere).

Comment: I tried smart unwrap and sphere projection but i just get some weird uv shapes.  The link is beyond my understanding of blender.  Everything else came with a UV and was hoping there was a way to figure out why this one UV doesn't appear like the others.  And I have no idea how the original UV for this looked like.  I don't think I can pull off the same UV shape that matches the texture that comes with the model.