# How to create a realistic horizon sun flare?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

This is my original render:
[image]

This is what I'm aiming for:
[image]

How do I make the sun flare look like that?
This is my setup file:

[image]

Comment: Much of the glow in the reference image is from illuminated atmosphere. Perhaps you need to use some volumetric shader?

Comment: are you sure the second image is "realistic"? see this reference from nasa.gov: https://www.nasa.gov/images/content/573237main_Catex_banner_large.jpg

Comment: I did some experimentation with fire and selecting some vertex groups and weight painting,It wasn't actually as similar as your pic but it came close.See,if you can achieve it.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker although my level of knowledge is that of an intermediate at best, I still don't know how, what you said, will help me

Comment: @m.ardito ok, well that wasn't an accurate representation, but now you know what kind of effect I'm chasing after, so how do I achieve it? XD

Comment: @3pointedit I've not used that shader before, how would you suggest, I go about it?

Comment: Have a look at this answer to get an idea http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45484/render-of-planet-earth-in-blender-render-and-cycles/45679#45679