# Why is this happening in my UV Unwrapping?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I just modeled my first character, and have performed my first UV wrapping. Everything looks ok, [image]but the UV's for the Eyeballs seem to fill the background behind the other figure elements, and are stacked on top of each other.[image] I've tried scaling them down, but there seems to be layer after layer after layer.[image] Pardon the pun but is this normal?

Comment: Thank you very much. The tutorial I was following never mentioned this step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have seams on the eye spheres, so either add seams, or try unwrapping with `Smart UV Project` or `Sphere Projection`.

What you are seeing is Blender unwrapping every individual face on top of each other.

I would highly recommend that you read the [Blender manual section on unwrapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/index.html) before continuing.

Also, see this question if you want details on unwrapping spheres in particular:

[What is the best way to unwrap a sphere?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10741/28015)