# How to create spherical textures?

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to create a texture for a sphere right now. With different Blender tutorials I get a texture on the sphere, but always with distortion at the north and south pole. I use Paint.net to create my textures, but I can't create spherical textures with it. Does anyone have a tool that converts a normal texture into a spherical texture?

Comment: It does mean not using paint.net, but one solution might be using the texture painting tools in blender to paint directly on the sphere.

Comment: Is your source texture something like a world map or a repeating that needs to be evenly patched out over the surface?

Comment: @gandalf3 Is a solution... yes ^^ but I think to create a better texture with some effects and more, no. But I will try it anyway.

Comment: @Jackdaw If it works, it'll be a planetary texture later.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since normal UV mapping creates distortions (from the vertex linear interpolation) the Generated UV coordinates usually gives better result.

Give the texture node the Generated UV coordinates and set the method to project to Sphere.

Here is a full tutorial: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/earth-cycles

[image]

Comment: It's perfect and it works. But I still need a spherical texture. How do I create a Spherical Texture?

Comment: I would say that it really depends on what you what to do. I don't know I they actually did this texture but I believe that NASA generated it from a lot of images and specialised software to map them together. 
In most cases where you need to create the texture yourself I would suggest doing a traditional UV map and 3d paint. If you want to add 2d textures to the surface they can be projected in various ways.

Comment: Do you have an example of an image that you want to have on the surface?

Comment: Here is a sample image of what I used for testing. [link](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/83/34/df/8334df22e8497cd185ba5c521205c920.png)

Comment: Yep, I would use a Texture with the Texture Paint tool and set the mapping to Stencil and the patch out the texture on the surface.

Answer (score 0):

Well, through UV mapping (it sounds intimidating but it's not THAT bad.) You can make a spherical object Much easier to texture, In edit mode, select edges on the "back"(or in this case probably the bottom) of the sphere going from the center STRAIGHT outward so you get an X or + shape that is equal on all points, hit CTRL+E to bring up the edges menu, select the option "Make Seam" then hit U to unwrap, that will leave your UV map with a Four pedaled flower shape.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to paint something on a sphere (you've mentioned using Paint.NET), you can use Tintaur (an iPhone/iPad app) to paint directly on a sphere and export ready to use textures from that app. Here's [a short video](https://youtu.be/r3lNxbeD7u0) on how to do this

Comment: Or you can can usre "sphere project" in the unwrapping options.