# How can I uniformly apply an image as a texture to an object?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to make an icosphere with a hexagonal pattern applied to it, but the image I'm using ends up getting completely warped and ripped along the faces. I don't know how to fix this, so please help.[image]

Comment: I'm not attempting to answer your question: I just wanted to make you aware about some issues with [balls and hexagons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btPqKAGyajM)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the node setup shown below. Change the parameters in the mapping node to move the image around. This might not work, as it is possible that the problem is in the UV projection, but I've already solved problems like this using this node setup.

I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: can you [edit] to explain why this might not work?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach this problem.

*1) UV Unwrapping*
There is a major problem with texturing a 3D sphere.
It is mathematically impossible to map a *2D texture* onto a *3D sphere* without distortion.

[Here is a great Stack Exchange thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere) where such situation and possible solutions are discussed in detail.

---

*2) Procedural textures*
If your texture is simple, you might want to use procedural texturing, instead of an image.
This way you can get a seamless pattern without any distortion.
[Here is an official Blender video about procedural textures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_deRNqDcwRk).

Good luck.
If you'll need any clarification, let me know.